# Codeigniter - How to get values as array to use in next select with where_not_in

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, where-clause

I have three tables; `user`, `car` and `user_x_car`. `user_x_car` holds users who own car; `user_id` and `car_id` are stored. I want to get users who don't own a car as follows:

```
$car_owner = $this->db->select()->from('user_x_car')->get()->result();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($car_owners); $i++)
    $car_owner_id[$i] = $car_owner[$i]->user_id;

$non_car_owner = $this->db->select()->from('user')->where_not_in('id', $car_owner_id)->get()->result();
```

I get what I want, however, is there any way to bypass the for loop in the middle which creates and array of id's selected in the first select. Is there any way to get array of selected `user_id`s directly?

Comment: check this line       `$$car_owner_id[$i] = $car_owner[$i]->user_id;` extra $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by two queries like

first one get all ids from  user_x_car table

```
$temp1=array();
$temp=$this->db->distinct()->select('user_id')->get('user_x_car')->result_array();
```

then from user table fetch those users who have no cars

```
foreach($temp as $each)
{
    array_push($temp1,$each['user_id']);
}
$rs=$this->db->where_not_in('id',$temp1)->get('user');
if($rs->num_rows()>0)
{
    $data=$rs->result_array();
    print_r($data);die;
}
```

$data will print all users who have no car. Please let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_unread_notifications_ids()
    {
        //get unread notifications ids
        $this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT(fknotification_id) as alll');
        $this->db->from("te_notification_status_tbl");
        $this->db->where('read_status',0);

        $ids=$this->db->get()->row();
        return $idss=str_replace(",","','",$ids->alll);
    }
```

and second function like this:

```
function get_unviewed_photos_events(){
        $idss = $this->get_unread_notifications_ids();

        $this->db->select('img.*',False);
        $this->db->from("te_notifications_tbl notif");
        $this->db->join('te_images_tbl img','img.id=notif.reference_id','LEFT OUTER');

        $this->db->where("notif.id IN('".$idss."')");
        $rslt = $this->db->get()->result_array();
        return $rslt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Query

```
$non_car_owner = $this->db->query('SELECT user.*
FROM user LEFT JOIN user_x_car ON user_x_car.id=user.id
WHERE table2.id IS NULL')->result();
```

Here users who are not on the table user_x_car

```
foreach($non_car_owner as $user){
   echo $user->user_id;
}
```